# Cláusula de arbitragem

Tags: debate, suporte, stackexchange

Há bastante movimentação no [metão](https://meta.stackexchange.com) acerca de mudanças nos termos de serviço da Stack Exchange. A parte mais polêmica é referente à arbitragem e a como excluir-se dela.

Aqui estão alguns tópicos relevantes que achei:

- [A new (2018) update to our Terms of Service is here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309746/176034) (observe a votação da pergunta e das respostas. Neste momento, a pergunta está com -235 votos e a resposta mais votada com +399).
- [How can we opt out from the arbitration clause of the new terms of service?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309786/176034)
- [We're examining the implementation of arbitration in the 2018 ToS update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309797/176034)
- [Electronic opt-out, correcting miscommunication, and additional questions answered about the 2018 ToS update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310061/176034)
- [Can we get an official statement about how the arbitration clause will be managed for foreign countries like European ones?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310236/176034)
- https://law.stackexchange.com/q/28180

Confesso que não entendi exatamente do que se trata esse lance de arbitragem. Pelo que entendi (não sei se entendi direito), trata-se do seguinte:

- A Stack Exchange alterou os seus termos de serviço para incluir uma cláusula de arbitragem.
- A cláusula de arbitragem diz que se você quiser litigar judicialmente com a Stack Exchange, deve fazê-lo por meio de uma entidade de arbitragem escolhida pela Stack Exchange.

Pelo meu entendimento, diversos usuários estão reclamando que isso então implica nessas consequências extremamente negativas:

- Se o usuário insistir em litigar judicialmente com a Stack Exchange por meio da justiça oficial, a causa seria imediatamente perdida porque os termos de serviço dizem que o usuário concorda em não fazer isso.
- Uma vez que a entidade de arbitragem é escolhida pela SE e paga por ela para tal, não há que se esperar que essa litigância tenha muitas chances de prosperar. Em outras palavras, a litigância não será julgada de forma justa e imparcial.
- Usuários que não concordarem com isso, têm um prazo de alguns poucos dias para enviar um e-mail para a SE solicitando a sua exclusão do processo de arbitragem para poderem litigar na justiça comum se assim desejarem. No entanto, a SE sabe que pouquíssimos usuários farão isso deixando essa mudança nas regras passar batido para quase todos.
- No caso de ocorrer algum grande vazamento de dados, violação de copyright ou outra coisa semelhantemente grave por causa de erro ou má fé da Stack Exchange (aconteceu com o Facebook recentemente no escândalo da Cambridge Analytica, já aconteceram vazamentos com o Yahoo! também), isso inviabilizaria aos usuários afetados buscarem na justiça por reparação. Também existe o medo que mesmo se hoje a Stack Exchange estiver agindo de forma honesta com seus usuários, se daqui há 5 anos ela for comprada pela Evilnet Inc, os novos donos podem não ser mais tão honestos assim.

E o lado positivo seria esse:

- A Stack Exchange fica mais protegida de pessoas que busquem iniciar litígios de má fé apenas para promover desgaste e despesas judiciais à empresa.

Face a isso tudo, as minhas perguntas são:

1. Se o que entendi está certo ou se entendi errado.
2. No que isso afeta para os usuários do SOpt que em sua grande maioria moram no Brasil ou em Portugal, vez que as leis dos Estados Unidos não se aplicam nesses países.

Comment: Ótima pergunta. Também tenho várias dúvidas sobre esse assunto.

Comment: Precisamos de um aDEVogado (mal aê, não resisto a um trocadilho infame).

Comment: Essa GDPR está fazendo todas as empresas mudarem os termos e nós usuários estamos todos apreensivos. Principalmente nós brasileiros que conhecemos nossos "árbitros justos". Vendo nos comentários, já houve casos de abusos nas cláusulas arbitrais/compromissórias [pela Wells Fargo](http://www.latimes.com/business/hiltzik/la-fi-hiltzik-wells-arbitration-20160926-snap-story.html). Isto que está deixando muitos usuários "com um pé atrás", mas as empresas de tecnologia também estão confusas... É uma mudança grande e muito recente, acho que a maioria dos advogados ainda não estão por dentro.

Comment: Aquilo que percebi foi que a arbitracao limita os meus recursos caso queira processar a StackExchange. Como eu NUNCA, por motivo algum, vou fazer isso. Isso não me preocupa.

Comment: Só uma pequena correção: A GDPR é uma legislação da União Européia, e não dos Estados Unidos!

Comment: @CássioRenan Mas a de arbitragem até onde entendo, só vale nos Estados Unidos. Isso dá a entender que a GDPR seria apenas uma desculpa esfarrapada para colocar a cláusula de arbitragem junto.

Comment: Realmente, eu não tinha percebido! Mas olhando denovo nas postagens (E no ToS), meu entendimento é de que a arbitragem será aplicável globalmente. Resta saber o que a legislação brasileira diz a respeito.

Comment: BTW, eu fiz o opt-out para arbitragem no dia em que saiu o anúncio no MSE. Mesmo que eu não tenha intenção nenhuma de processar o StackExchange, simplesmente não há razão nenhuma para não fazê-lo.

Answer (score 2):

Eu acho que dificilmente alguém daqui processaria ou seria processado pela Stack Exchange. Mas se tem gente que processa a Apple por incêndio em avião...

Não posso falar por todos os países lusófonos, mas no Brasil EULA's e termos de serviço são considerados contratos de adesão. [E sobre tais contratos](https://raphaelfunchalcarneiro.jusbrasil.com.br/artigos/203332111/o-foro-contratual-e-a-sumula-de-jurisprudencia-n-335-do-stf):

> “não prevalece o foro contratual de eleição, se configurada que tal indicação, longe de constituir-se uma livre escolha, mas mera adesão a cláusula pré-estabelecida pela instituição mutuante, implica em dificultar a defesa da parte mais fraca, em face dos ônus que terá para acompanhar o processo em local distante daquele em que reside e, também, onde foi celebrado o mútuo.” (STJ, CC nº 23968, DJ 16/11/1999)

É claro, eu não sou advogado. Então se alguém realmente processar a SE, se basear nisso pra mudar o foro e falhar miseravelmente, eu vou apenas apontar o dedo e rir.