# Comunicado de "Termos de Uso e Política de Privacidade" está em Inglês

Tags: suporte, tradução

Hoje reparei que apareceu na base da janela do StackOverflow PT e no nosso Meta um aviso de  **"Termos de Uso e Política de Privacidade"** que está em Inglês conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> This site uses cookies to deliver our services and to show you
>   relevant ads and job listings. By using our site, you acknowledge that
>   you have read and understand our Cookie Policy, Privacy Policy, and
>   our Terms of Service. Your use of Stack Overflow’s Products and
>   Services, including the Stack Exchange Network, is subject to these
>   policies and terms.

Comment: Provavelmente relacioado [Cláusula de arbitragem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7075/3635)

Comment: Apenas para constar, creio ser improvável traduzirem isto, já que a mensagem é global em todos sites da rede. Mas acho a pergunta totalmente valida para a tradução, afinal é um site em português, se a mensagem puder ser traduzida com certeza será melhor.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento pensei a mesma coisa, provavelmente está ligado a atualização da Cláusula de arbitragem. Acho que pelo menos o "alerta" poderia ser em PT, já os links fica complicado traduzir tudo imagino... Acredito que boa parte de quem frequenta o pt.stackoverflow.com não acessa o Meta e não deve estar cientes da mudança na política. Por isso seria interessante traduzir pelo menos o Aviso ao meu ver. Isso se for possível né.

Comment: Não acho que isso (a) tenha diretamente a ver com a cláusula de arbitragem (b). Tanto (a) quanto (b) estão relacionados ao [GDPR](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310321/176034) (c). No entanto, não vejo relação relevante entre (a) e (b) que não seja apenas que estão vindo juntos por causa do GDPR.